# How to parse a set of Command APDU

Tags: android

In one of my application, i am getting an APDU command packet from the server,which have number of APDU's with in it. I need to break the packet in APDU's array..basically extracting the APDU's from the packet and store them as apdu array.

The APDU command i am getting is like..

82 05 D7 22 15 84 82 01 00 10 3E C5 2B 8F 0B
01 C1 F7 57 29 27 06 BA FA F6 5D 22 1D 84 E2 00
00 18 92 00 0D 9F 10 0A 06 01 0A 03 00 00 00 0F
08 00 8E 93 F8 CA 3C 72 FD AA 22 1A 84 E2 00 01
15 92 07 0A 82 02 20 00 94 04 10 01 03 00 F6 0C
95 36 C0 F4 A2 36 22 4C 84 E2 00 02 47 91 02 3C
A5 3A 9F 38 1B 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A
02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 4E 14
BF 0C 14 9F 5A 05 31 08 40 08 40 9F 4D 02 14 05
BF 63 04 DF 20 01 80 5F 2D 02 65 6E 34 FD 93 33
CC 12 30 BE 22 27 84 E2 00 03 22 91 05 17 82 02
20 21 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 01 8A 01 00 8C

so i need to extract score of APDU's from it and use it to communicate it with the Secure element.

Please let me know if there is any third party parsers are available.

Comment: Just google `apdu api java` and voilá.

Comment: thanks for the reply....but i wanted to know the start and end point of  and APDU command..i have gone through the specs and Command apdu format...command APdu structure looks like below:                                        CLA INS P1 P2 LC Data Le

Comment: ok, i have got the answer..Apologies for notifying it with little bit delay..OK back to the topic...if you are recieving a set of command script then you can search for 22 tag..it will be the start of any APDU command.The next byte will be the length of the APDU command.